# Regular Expression Exclusions

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a method that takes in a string and returns any characters it finds that don't match a regular expression. I can't seem to get it to work with this case though.

1. Digits are allowed anywhere
2. If there is a negative symbol, it must be in the first space.
3. Alpha characters are allowed in the last position if they are one of the following:

   A-R (uppercase)

   { or }

I have a regular expression which returns only characters that match these requirements:

```
   [\d]|^[-]|[A-R{}]$
```

but I can't seem to modify it to return any digits that DON'T match. Here are some samples:

Valid:

```
12345
-12345
1234B
-1234B
1234{
-1234}
```

Invalid:

```
12-345 
12345- 
B12345 
12B345 
{12345 
12}345
```

Or any other character:

```
"12345 
12345^ 
$%^&# 
STUVWXYZ
```

Comment: You want to return the non-matching token? Or just true/false?

Comment: I want to return all non matching tokens

Comment: Non-matchings tokens, or tokens that are not contained within a match? Careful, the two are different.

Comment: In the valid inputs I should get nothing back.

In the other ones I should get back (in order)
-
-
B
B
{
}
"
^
$%^&#
STUVWXYZ

Comment: Why shouldn't the first one return "12-"? Or "2-"? Or even ""? All of these are non-matching strings, and all of them appear before your suggested string.

Answer (score 1):

```
-?\d+[A-R{}]?
```

Should do the job

Comment: I need it to return all non matching tokens.

Comment: Every other token is non matching. I can split some matching tokens to create an unmatching token.